# What do you call a song that starts with its chorus instead of its verse?

Tags: terminology, technique

I am listening to the bollywood song "Challa" from the movie: "Jab Tak Hai Jaan 2012".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9a4izd3Rvdw

At ***00:28***, I feel the song suddenly starts with its chorus instead of its verse. What do we call this type of music?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "starts in the middle"?  Do you mean that it starts with its chorus instead of its verse?  Or do you mean that it has an extended instrumental section before the vocals start?

Comment: @ChrisSunami I edited the question.

Comment: This is something very common, I never heard a specific name for this...

Comment: This practice is more common with `pop` music